# NHibernate Named Query Not Returning All Fields

Tags: c#, ms-access, nhibernate, group-by, named-query

I have the following Named Query defined in Forecast.hbm.xml:

```
SELECT 
    c.ForecastedYear,
    s.Description,
    Sum(c.NumTrees) AS NumTrees
FROM 
    EcoForecasts AS f INNER JOIN 
    (EcoForecastCohorts AS c INNER JOIN EcoStrata AS s ON s.StrataKey = c.StratumKey) 
    ON f.ForecastKey = c.ForecastKey
WHERE 
    f.ForecastKey = :guid
GROUP BY 
    c.ForecastedYear,
    c.StratumKey,
    s.Description
ORDER BY 
    s.Description,
    c.ForecastedYear;
```

I call the query in the C# file NumTreesByStrataReport.cs like this:

```
IList<Result> results = _input.GetNamedQuery("NumTreesByStrata")
                              .SetGuid("guid", _iSess.ForecastKey.Value)
                              .List<object[]>()
                              .Select(result => new Result {
                                  Year     = Convert.ToInt16(result[0]),
                                  Strata   = Convert.ToString(result[1]),
                                  NumTrees = Convert.ToInt64(result[2])
                              })
                              .ToList();

return results;
```

However, this code throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because the `.List<object[]>()` part is returning a list of object arrays with only 3 elements.  The `s.Description` field is not being returned.

If I run the SQL query in my database engine (Microsoft Access), then all 3 columns are returned. Why is NHibernate not able to do what the database can do and return all the selected fields?

Comment: Have you profiled the SQL being generated by NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a result to bean transformer instead, it will be much cleaner code.

```
return _session.GetNamedQuery("NumTreesByStrata")
    .SetGuid("guid", forecastKeyValue)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Result)))
    .List<Result>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.  It turns out the issue was actually with my mapping file:

```
    <sql-query name="NumTreesByStrata">
        <return-scalar column="ForecastedYear" type="Int16"/>
        <return-scalar column="NumTrees" type="Int64"/>
        <![CDATA[
          SELECT c.ForecastedYear,
          ...
        ]]>
    </sql-query>
```

I added the missing `<return-scalar column="Description" type="string"/>` element to make it work.

> I would suggest using a result to bean transformer instead, it will be much cleaner code.

Thanks for the suggestion Alexey, I didn't know you could do that!